# Match a Query to a Regular Expression in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, database

I'm trying to find a way to match a query to a regular expression in a database. As far as I can tell (although I'm no expert), while most DBMS like MySQL have a [regex option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) for searching, you can only do something like:

*Find all rows in Column 1 that match the regex in my query.*

What I want to be able to do is the opposite, i.e.:

*Find all rows in Column 1 such that the regex in Column 1 matches my query.*

Simple example - say I had a database structured like so:

```
+----------+-----------+  
| Column 1 |  Column 2 |
+----------+-----------+
|  [a-z]+  |  whatever |
+----------+-----------+
|  [\w]+   |  whatever |
+----------+-----------+
|  [0-9]+  |  whatever |
+----------+-----------+
```

So if I queried **"dog"**, I would want it to return the rows with [a-z]+ and [\w]+, and if I queried **123**, it would return the row with [0-9]+.

If you know of a way to do this in SQL, a short SELECT example or a link with an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Oracle didn't support regex's till 10g, SQL Server added support in v2005.  There's no ANSI standard syntax that I'm aware of - regex is, but the function(s) used to do this will be different between vendors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MySQL (and may be other databases too):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "dog" RLIKE(`Column 1`)
```

Comment: Just a quick update -- I found that it only worked in MySQL if I structured the query as so:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE "dog" RLIKE(Column 1)

Comment: How would you do this in Rails Active Record query interface?

Comment: You probably need to post this as separate question.

Answer (score 1):

In [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html) it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'dog' ~ "Column 1";
```