# MySQL/Regexp: Partial regexp match

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a bunch of regular expressions in a MySQL table. I want to know whether a given string matches a part of any regular expression or not.

Eg:

```
+----+--------------------------------+
| id | regexps                        |
+----+--------------------------------+
| 1  | foo-[0-9]*\.example\.com       |
| 2  | (bar|tux)-[0-9]*\.example\.com |
+----+--------------------------------+
```

(The `regexps` attribute is of `VARCHAR` type)

`foo-11.example.com` matches the first regexp.

I want a MySQL query that returns the first row with the given string as `foo-11`

Comment: And if it's only `foo`? And if it's only `f`?

Comment: Well, only `foo` should ideally return the first row. i am not sure about only `f`

Comment: Is changing the patterns an option?

Comment: no.. Also, i dont want any MySQL functions.

Comment: And do you only want submatches from the beginning of the pattern? Or should `xam` return both lines?

Comment: I suppose you're trying to simulate regex groups capture - and that's not possible in MySQL natively. I can't figure out how can you build desired link between string and pattern. It either match string or not.

Comment: @m.buettner `example` should return both. doesn't matter what `xam` returns

Answer (score 0):

This should do it on MySql:

```
select * from table t where 'foo-11.example.com' rlike t.data;
```

There are other ways in PostGreSQL. Here's the link from where I have referenced this:

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm
2. [Match a Query to a Regular Expression in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842354/match-a-query-to-a-regular-expression-in-sql)

PS: Using * is tricky though!

Comment: i have no problem in matching `foo-11.example.com`. I want to match `foo-11`